# Returning a list of primes in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, logic, primes

I am trying to create a list that returns number primes until a N number.

I have this code that indicates if a number is prime:

```
is_prime(2).  
is_prime(3). 
is_prime(P) :- integer(P), P > 3, P mod 2 =\= 0, \+has_factor(P,3). 
has_factor(N,L) :- N mod L =:= 0. 
has_factor(N,L) :- L * L < N, L2 is L + 2, has_factor(N,L2).
```

that works very well.

My logic is: to test if N is prime, if so add N in a list, if doesn't just ignore and test to N-1. Here the code:

```
primeList(N,C):- is_prime(N) -> append(N,[C],L),fail; N1 is N-1, primeList(N1,L).
```

And it doesn't work! How could I fix this problem following my logic?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a variable in Prolog is instantiated (has a value) in a predicate clause, it can't be reassigned. So you can't keep appending to the list `L` in `primeList`.

But you can use `findall` and `between`:

```
prime_list(N, C) :-
    findall(X, (between(2,N,X), is_prime(X)), C).
```